# Zenoss: Getting SNMP stats over SSH

Tags: ssh, monitoring, performance-monitoring, snmp, zenoss

I have the SSH connection working. I have it successfully modeling the device (Ubuntu Server, in this case).

What I can't get to work is the SNMP portion. It sounds like I have to custom add the snmpwalk command when doing monitoring over SSH - in other words, have Zenoss connect via SSH, and then run an arbitrary command against the client (in this case, an snmpwalk), and then parse the results.

What I need help doing is:

1. Add the snmpwalk command to the SSH monitoring
2. Parsing the output and getting the data back into the charts

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand the question, but when I was doing SSH modeling, I had trouble getting device information back from the server.  I had to do the following:

- Setup SSH Key based authentication (I created a user name zenoss on the remote machine, and disabled the password)
- Install the ZenPlugins on the remote machine: http://sourceforge.net/projects/zenoss/files/zenplugins/zenplugins/  I also had to install the PythonSetupTools for my distribution.
- Change the modeler plugins. Remove zenoss.snmp.* plugins, and add the corresponding zenoss.cmd.* plugins (for linux, osx, etc)
- Remodel Device.

My exact commands for a remote CentOS/RHEL 5 based device were:

```
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/zenoss/files/zenplugins/zenplugins/Zenoss-Plugins-2.0.4-1.py24.noarch.rpm/download
rpm -i Zenoss-Plugins-2.0.4-1.py24.noarch.rpm 
wget http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c7.tar.gz#md5=dedbf6a4f71cd6deaf13ee885054f16b
tar zxvf setuptools-0.6c7.tar.gz
cd setuptools-0.6c7
python ./setup.py install
cd /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/
chmod 775 setuptools*
```

Hope that helps.. Took me quite a while to figure out.

Comment: I'll have to give this a try next time round. I definitely didn't do the plugin install on the remote machine (as I recall from April, I interpreted the documentation as it not being necessary, though maybe I completely misread it), and I didn't do the PythonSetupTools. This has since become a moot point, but I do appreciate the answer since, in a few months, I'll likely be doing another Zenoss setup. I'll give this a shot again and see if it works this way.

Comment: I have found the tool to be excellent, but the documentation rather lacking, and the forum to be very hit or miss :)